# How to connect to a database through a Paramiko Tunnel (or similar package)

Tags: python, database-connection, paramiko, tunneling

I am having serious issues setting up a proper tunnel in paramiko to enable a database connection.  I have reviewed the example 'forward.py', but am not understanding how to then link the database connection to it.  Any pointers woudl be much appreciated.

I think I need something the following:

```
t = paramiko.Transport((hostname, port))
t.connect(username=username, password=password, hostkey=hostkey) 
c = paramiko.Channel(t)

#something about assigning a local port to this connection

connection = psycopg2.connect(connectionstring)
#and do my stuff

connection.close()
c.close()
t.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have created your ssh tunnel using the forward.py script ; you can use the ssh tunnel to [connect](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/module.html) to postgresql like this:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(database="test", host="localhost", port=<forward_port>)
```

Comment: I know this is right, I am just not using forward.py properly.

Comment: Turns out I am not sure why I thought this suited my uses.  It is better for me to maintain a tunnel through the external program ssh than to try to set it up in Python.

Answer (score 1):

I had same serious issues getting paramiko to work too but ended up doing it with another library (sshtunnel) that wraps and simplifies paramiko's tunneling.

You can check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31639144/1309854) in another similar question with some sample code to use it.