# telnet to a device from server, over an existing ssh connection between client / server

Tags: python, ssh, telnet, paramiko

Here is the issue. I was using my script to connect to a device directly over a telnet connection (**from my windows desktop** <=(telnet)=> **to the device**).  Basicly, my script run some commands in [TL1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transaction_Language_1), capture the output and proceed according the parameter values...  pretty straight forward.

This device will be install on another network, which i can't reach anymore by telnet directly.  Now, i have to start an ssh connection on the specific server and then, start the telnet session from there. (**from my windows desktop** <=(ssh)=> **server** <=(telnet)=> **to the device**)

I understand the basic of paramiko... i found that code on [jessenoler](http://jessenoller.com/2009/02/05/ssh-programming-with-paramiko-completely-different/) website:

```
import paramiko
ssh.connect('127.0.0.1', username='jesse', password='lol')
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("uptime")
type(stdin)
stdout.readlines()
# output:
# ['13:35  up 11 days,  3:13, 4 users, load averages: 0.14 0.18 0.16\n']
```

I can't figure out how i could initiate a telnet from the server...  Should i use :

```
ssh.exec_command("telnet 10.10.10.10 10001")
```

I know the easiest way to solve my problem is to have install python on the server, but i can't.  Someone faced that kind a problem before?  Thanks for the input! :)

Comment: that would establish a telnet connection to the device, true. But it would be only between the device and the server, not trivially accessible from within your script. I'd create a SSH Tunnel between the desktop and the server (using ssh -L), and telnet through it from the desktop to the device directly, using the telnetlib module.

Comment: Hi ch3ka, thanks for the input!  Never done that before.  I guess i have to do the forward on the server side. or i could initiate the ssl -L only on my desktop?  i'm a bit confuse.  i'll keep reading about forwarding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should setup an SSH tunnel instead of opening a normal connection. This can be done from the command line on your client with `-L localport:server:remoteport`, or it can be done from python with `paramiko`.

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8292891/164277) and the [linked gist](https://gist.github.com/1399529) for details of how to do it with Python.

When you've set this up, you should connect with telnet to `localhost` on the port specified as localport.