# ssh using python and paramiko module

Tags: python, paramiko

This is my first post and I am very new in python and paramiko. My requirement is to:

- ssh server1.com
- ssh from server1 to server2.com
- ssh from server2 to server3.com
- run multiple UNIX commands on server3.com like declog, decrypt, scp, grep etc.... and finally create .tgz file
- Move .tgz file from server3 to server2 to server1 to local

I did Google and found that python script with paramiko module can do this job. I was able to ssh to server1 but don't know how to ssh server2 and server3.

Code:

```
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.load_host_keys("/cygwin/home/skhome/.ssh/known_hosts")
    privkey = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file ("/cygwin/home/skhome/.ssh/id_rsa")
    ssh.connect('server1.com', username='sk000g',pkey=privkey )
    # Not sure how to connect sever2, server3 and execute UNIX commands
```

Thanks,
Shah

Comment: I recommend to use `pexpect` rather than paramiko for a job like this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5852481/paramiko-ssh-port-forwarding-to-get-sql-dump

Comment: @spinus thanks for the answer. I am running my driver script in windows 7 environment. Can i still use pexepct ? Thanks