# Paramiko: Port Forwarding Around A NAT Router

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

### Configuration

- **LOCAL:** A local machine that will create an ssh connection and issue commands on a REMOTE box.
- **PROXY:** An EC-2 instance with ssh access to both LOCAL and REMOTE.
- **REMOTE:** A remote machine sitting behind a NAT Router (inaccessible by LOCAL, but will open a connection to PROXY and allow LOCAL to tunnel to it).

### Port Forwarding Steps (via command line)

1. Create an ssh connection from REMOTE to PROXY to forward ssh traffic on port 22 on the REMOTE machine to port 8000 on the PROXY server.

   > # Run from the REMOTE machine
   > ssh -N -R 0.0.0.0:8000:localhost:22 PROXY_USER@PROXY_HOSTNAME
2. Create an ssh tunnel from LOCAL to PROXY and forward ssh traffic from LOCAL:1234 to PROXY:8000 (which then forwards to REMOTE:22).

   > # Run from LOCAL machine
   > ssh -L 1234:localhost:8000 PROXY_USER@PROXY_HOSTNAME
3. Create the forwarded ssh connection from LOCAL to REMOTE (via PROXY).

   > # Run from LOCAL machine in a new terminal window
   > ssh -p 1234 REMOTE_USER@localhost
   >
   > # I have now ssh'd to the REMOTE box and can run commands

### Paramiko Research

I have looked at a [handful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5852481/paramiko-ssh-port-forwarding-to-get-sql-dump) of [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294919/port-forwarding-with-paramiko) related to port forwarding using Paramiko, but they don't seem to address this specific situation.

### My Question

How can I use Paramiko to run steps 2 and 3 above? I essentially would like to run:

```
import paramiko

# Create the tunnel connection
tunnel_cli = paramiko.SSHClient()
tunnel_cli.connect(PROXY_HOSTNAME, PROXY_PORT, PROXY_USER)

# Create the forwarded connection and issue commands from LOCAL on the REMOTE box
fwd_cli = paramiko.SSHClient()
fwd_cli.connect('localhost', LOCAL_PORT, REMOTE_USER)
fwd_cli.exec_command('pwd')
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

A detailed explanation of what Paramiko is doing "under the hood" can be found at [@bitprohet's blog here](http://bitprophet.org/blog/2012/11/05/gateway-solutions/).

Assuming the configuration above, the code I have working looks something like this:

```
from paramiko import SSHClient

# Set up the proxy (forwarding server) credentials
proxy_hostname = 'your.proxy.hostname'
proxy_username = 'proxy-username'
proxy_port = 22

# Instantiate a client and connect to the proxy server
proxy_client = SSHClient()
proxy_client.load_host_keys('~/.ssh/known_hosts/')
proxy_client.connect(
    proxy_hostname,
    port=proxy_port,
    username=proxy_username,
    key_filename='/path/to/your/private/key/'
)

# Get the client's transport and open a `direct-tcpip` channel passing
# the destination hostname:port and the local hostname:port
transport = proxy_client.get_transport()
dest_addr = ('0.0.0.0', 8000)
local_addr = ('127.0.0.1', 1234)
channel = transport.open_channel("direct-tcpip", dest_addr, local_addr)

# Create a NEW client and pass this channel to it as the `sock` (along with
# whatever credentials you need to auth into your REMOTE box
remote_client = SSHClient()
remote_client.load_host_keys(hosts_file)
remote_client.connect('localhost', port=1234, username='remote_username', sock=channel)

# `remote_client` should now be able to issue commands to the REMOTE box
remote_client.exec_command('pwd')
```

Comment: Indeed epic. Thank you !!

Comment: I believe there's redundancy in the code. If you specify `sock`, the `hostname` and `port` is ignored (it's already part of the channel after all).

Answer (score 1):

Is the point solely to bounce SSH commands off PROXY or do you need to forward other, non SSH ports too?

If you just need to SSH into the REMOTE box, Paramiko supports both SSH-level gatewaying (tells the PROXY sshd to open a connection to REMOTE and forward SSH traffic on LOCAL's behalf) and ProxyCommand support (forwards all SSH traffic through a local command, which could be anything capable of talking to the remote box).

Sounds like you want the former to me, since PROXY clearly already has an sshd running. If you check out a copy of Fabric and search around for 'gateway' you will find pointers to how Fabric uses Paramiko's gateway support (I don't have time to dig up the specific spots myself right now.)