# How to connect bastion to aws ec2 instances in python

Tags: python-3.x, ssh, amazon-ec2, paramiko, pyopenssl

My deployment aws environment is using bastion host to allow connection to all different aws ec2 machines. I am using [paramiko](http://www.paramiko.org/) and able to make connection with [bastion](http://docs.python.org/2/library/bastion.html).

```
pemkey_path = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file("xyz.pem")
paramiko_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
paramiko_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
print("connecting")
bastion_conn = paramiko_client.connect( hostname = "ec2-xxx.compute.amazonaws.com", username = "ec2-user", pkey = pemkey_path)
print("connected")
```

Now I want to connect to ec2 instance from this bastion connection and perform some commands to this ec2-instance how can I do this ?

Comment: My problem was solved by the explanation given at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18968069/paramiko-port-forwarding-around-a-nat-router/19039769#19039769