# Translate Oracle SQL Developer SSH Host w/ Local Port Forward Connection to Python

Tags: python, oracle-sqldeveloper, paramiko, ssh-tunnel, proxy-server

I'm trying to create a Python connection to a remote server through an SSH Jump Host (one I've successfully created in Oracle SQL Developer) but can't replicate in Python. Can connect to SSH Host successfully but fail to forward the port to the remote server due to timeout or error opening tunnels. Safe to assume my code is incorrect rather than server issues. Also need a solution that doesn't use the "with SSHTunnelForwarder() as server:" approach because I need a continuous session similar to OSD/cx_Oracle session rather than a batch processing function.

Similar examples provided here (and elsewhere) using paramiko, sshtunnel, and cx_Oracle haven't worked for me. Many other examples don't require (or at least clearly specify) separate login credentials for the remote server. I expect the critical unclear piece is which local host + port to use, which my SQL Developer connection doesn't require explicitly (although I've tried using the ports OSD chooses, not at the same time).

Closest match I think was best answer from [paramiko-port-forwarding-around-a-nat-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18968069/paramiko-port-forwarding-around-a-nat-router/19039769#19039769)

### OSD Inputs

**SSH Host**  
- host = proxy_hostname  
- port = proxy_port = 22  
- username = proxy_username  
- password = proxy_password

**Local Port Forward**  
- host = remote_hostname  
- port = remote_port = 1521  
- automatically assign local port = True

**Connection**  
- username = remote_username  
- password = remote_password  
- connection type = SSH  
- SID = remote_server_sid

### Python Code

i.e., analogous code from [paramiko-port-forwarding-around-a-nat-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18968069/paramiko-port-forwarding-around-a-nat-router/19039769#19039769)

```
import paramiko
from paramiko import SSHClient

# Instantiate a client and connect to the proxy server
proxy_client = SSHClient()
proxy_client.connect(
    proxy_hostname,
    port=proxy_port,
    username=proxy_username,
    password=proxy_password)

# Get the client's transport and open a `direct-tcpip` channel passing
# the destination hostname:port and the local hostname:port
transport = proxy_client.get_transport()
dest_addr = (remote_hostname,remote_port)
local_addr = ('localhost',55587)
channel = transport.open_channel("direct-tcpip", dest_addr, local_addr)

# Create a NEW client and pass this channel to it as the `sock` (along 
# with whatever credentials you need to auth into your REMOTE box
remote_client = SSHClient()
remote_client.connect(
    'localhost',
    port=55587, 
    username=remote_username, 
    password=remote_password,
    sock=channel)
```

Rather than a connection to the remote server I get

```
transport.py in start_client()
SSHException: Error reading SSH protocol banner
```

Comment: Your `remote_client` code does match that of https://stackoverflow.com/q/18968069/850848 - You connect to remote_hostname:remote_port, while you should connect to localhost:22. Also 22 is a bad choice of a port, you may need to use a higher port number, as 22 might conflict with existing SSH local server - also on *nix, you need root permissions to open 22 port anyway. Just strictly follow the code from the other question.

Comment: I also do not understand how `SSHTunnelForwarder` prevents your from doing *"continuous session"*

Comment: Changing local_addr to port 55587 (a successfully used port with SQL Developer) and remote_client.connect('localhost',port=55587...) returns the same error.

Comment: How exactly are you using 55587 in SQL developer? + What is `1521`? Is that a database port? If it is, then you obviously cannot use SSH client (`remote_client = SSHClient()`) to connect to it.

Comment: The successful SQLDev connection automatically assigns a local port and 55587 has been selected in the past. I don't know anything about 1521 except that's the Local Port Forward port on the remote machine where I used to login directly from Python before needing to go through the Jump Host.

Comment: In your code `remote_port` is not *"Local Port Forward port"*. --- It would help, if you show us your working configuration from your database client.

Comment: Not following- the analogous SQLDev connection uses remote_port/1521 as its Local Port Forward Port input. My question is what are the equivalent Python inputs via paramiko or similar approach. What other info is required for Python that wasn't required for SQLDev (other than the local port info)?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your SQLDev  configuration?

Comment: Martin, thanks for your comments. They helped me feel more comfortable trying some of the things that didn't "feel right" but were ultimately necessary for the solution. I've been working on this for a few weeks on and off, should have posted sooner.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

Finally figured out a solution! Analogous to OSD's automatic local port assignment and doesn't require SSHTunnelForwarder's with statement. Hope it can help someone else- use the question's OSD input variables with...

```
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
import cx_Oracle 

server=SSHTunnelForwarder(
    (proxy_hostname,proxy_port),
    ssh_username=proxy_username,
    ssh_password=proxy_password,
    remote_bind_address=(remote_hostname,remote_port))

server.start()
db=cx_Oracle.connect('%s/%s@%s:%s/%s'%(remote_username,remote_password,'localhost',server.local_bind_port,remote_server_sid))
# do something with db
server.close()
```

Comment: `with` statement is not a problem either. You just need to *"do something with db"* withing the `with` statement.

Comment: 'with' statement creates function-like batch processing, which isn't what I want when I'm working with a DB throughout the day and want to interact with intermediate steps before writing the next line of code. 'with' requires me to reconnect each time.