# cx_Oracle DatabaseError: ORA-12170:

Tags: python-3.x, oracle, cx-oracle

I'm trying to get a connection from `python (3.7)` to a remote `oracle` DB using the code below:

```py
import cx_Oracle # Version 7.2.2
import sshtunnel
import socket

HOST = "HOST"
USRNAME = "Me"
hostname = socket.gethostname()  
IPAddr = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)


with sshtunnel.SSHTunnelForwarder(
                         (HOST, 22), 
                         ssh_username = USRNAME,
                         ssh_pkey='~/.ssh/dumpserver',
                         remote_bind_address=(IPAddr, 22)
                         ) as server: 

        conn = cx_Oracle.connect('testuser','password', 'oracle/db', encoding="UTF-8")
        print(conn.version)
```

I get the following ERROR:

> DatabaseError: ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred.

I've tried to read up on this at

- https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/connection_handling.html
- [cx_Oracle & Connecting to Oracle DB Remotely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245465/cx-oracle-connecting-to-oracle-db-remotely/1870849#1870849)
- https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/issues/158

But did not get any smarter and I can't get it to work :( Any ideas pointers etc. are very welcome. Also if someone has alternative code snipets on how to send an oracle query to remote - f.eks using `paramiko` that would be great.

Thanks, F

Comment: I think your remote_bind_address should probably be `("127.0.0.1",1521)`? Try looking at the SSH tunnel documentation, I think you want Example 1 - https://sshtunnel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: See also this example from your third link: https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/issues/158#issuecomment-382760857

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But the IP is not the problem, I get a working ssh connection with `sshtunnel`  (running `server.local_bind_port` returns a port)

Answer (score 0):

I found one Oracle SSH Tunnel code, which is very similar to your code in [SSH Tunnel To Server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56286627/12422518)

About the IP issue, your Error code shows that you may have wrong IP for Oracle Service please check this entry [lsnrctl status](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26649237/12422518)