# Python - SSH Tunnel Setup and MySQL DB Access

Tags: mysql-python, paramiko

I am trying to connect to my server from my local(windows) and access the MySQL DB

With the below code setting up the SSH tunnel through putty, I am not able to access the 
MySQL DB.

```
con = None
con = mdb.connect(user='user',passwd='password',db='database',host='127.0.0.1',port=3308)
cur = con.cursor()
```

With the below code, I am using paramiko to setup SSH tunnel which is successful but I am not able to connect to MySQL DB

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('host', username='username', password='password')

con = None
con = mdb.connect(user='user',passwd='password',db='database',host='127.0.0.1',port=3308)
cur = con.cursor()

Error:
Error 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (10061)
```

Do I have change the MySQL connecting string settings to access MySQL DB using paramiko If not I need to add anymore parameter for paramiko to simulate SSH tunnel setup like putty.

Answer (score 7):

You can use sshtunnel wrapper for paramiko and save you headaches ;)

```
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
import MySQLdb

with SSHTunnelForwarder(
         ('host', 22),
         ssh_password="password",
         ssh_username="username",
         remote_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 3308)) as server:

    con = None
    con = mdb.connect(user='user',passwd='password',db='database',host='127.0.0.1',port=server.local_bind_port)
    cur = con.cursor()
```

Comment: yup, this one worked. In case you are using id_rsa just replace `ssh_password` parameter with `ssh_private_key=PATH_TO_id_rsa`

Comment: Yep! that's another option ;)

Comment: what is mdb ? I have an error which says "mdb not defined". after replacing it with "MySQLdb" (just a guess), I know have an error:  `File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 202, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2006, 'MySQL server has gone away')`

Comment: Ok, I got it - I was working with cur beyond the scope of "with .. server:" construction ! 4 spaces did the magic (as usual in Python !)

Comment: This example was made directly for Earnests question thats why kept it as mdb, so I left things as per his sample. Glad you got it sorted!