# Run ssh port forwarding in background before connecting to mySql server

Tags: python, mysql, portforwarding, pexpect

I am writing a python script that will open up an ssh connection to do port forwarding, something like this:

```
import pexpect
import sqlalchemy as sql

child = pexpect.spawnu('ssh -L 3306:remote.db.host:3306 username@hostname')
child.expect (u'password:')
child.sendline ('xxxxxxxx')

while child.isalive():
    try:
        engine = sql.create_engine('mysql+pymysql://ro:xxxx@127.0.0.1:3306/testdb')
        connection = engine.connect()
        #run queries 
        connection.close()
        break
    finally:
        child.close()
```

This script is spiting out this error and I don't know what to do.

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' ([Errno 61] Connection refused)")
```

If I use 'child.interact()' after child.sendline(..), I will end up logged in to the forwarding server. But what I really want is to go on and run a sql query to fetch data from the remote database on
localhost port 3306.

So, how can I put the ssh connection to run in the background? I need to make sure that connection is made before I can connect to mysql server.

Comment: Have you seen: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sshtunnel ?

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack Yes. Unfortunately it didn't work for me. The terminal just hangs in there without doing anything and I have to manually kill it.  Without python I usually execute this cmd - "ssh -L 3306:remote.db.host:3306 username@hostname" and type in my password in the shell. Once authenticated I access the database in mysql workbench by connecting to localhost:3306.

Comment: pypi.python.org/pypi/sshtunnel is a native Python tunnel. It doesn't run in your terminal....

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack I used it in a Python script as mentioned here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12989866/python-ssh-tunnel-setup-and-mysql-db-access/31639144#31639144 and the terminal just got hanging in there without doing anything and finally I had to kill it manually.

Comment: works for me. It sounds like you're not using it correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are nearly there. 
Try using the `-N` argument to your ssh command so it returns immediately after creating the tunnel: `ssh -LN 3306:remote.db.host:3306 username@hostname`.

I would also use ssh keys (potentially sans passphrase or use a keyring of some sort) so you don't have to use pexpect.

try creating a bash script to create the tunnel and run the python script like so:

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh -LN 3306:remote.db.host:3306 username@hostname
python your_script_name
```

Comment: I used the option as -N -L and now I get this error: sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' ([Errno 61] Connection refused)")

Comment: if I use the argument as -LN I get the below error: 

raise EOF('End Of File (EOF). Empty string style platform.')
pexpect.exceptions.EOF: End Of File (EOF). Empty string style platform.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):..
...raise EOF(msg)
pexpect.exceptions.EOF: End Of File (EOF). Empty string style platform.
<pexpect.pty_spawn.spawn object at 0x10140bc88>
command: /usr/bin/ssh
args: ['/usr/bin/ssh', '-LN', '3306:remote.db.host:3306', 'username@host']
..before (last 100 chars): "Bad local forwarding specification 'N'\r\n".

Comment: I'm not sure what to say about the pexepect stuff. I would try to make it work with a passphraseless ssh key first to be sure it's working properly.

Comment: also, can you check and see if the sockets from the ssh command are open on your client and server? You can use `netstat` or `ss` to do this. check it before and after to make sure the sockets are actually opened. You might want to put a sleep in your python code after the call to initiate the tunnel

Comment: If I manually create the tunnel and run this command - sudo lsof -i -n | egrep '\<ssh\>' 

I see the following:    

    TCP xx.xxx.17.87:62082->xx.x.xxx.133:ssh (ESTABLISHED)
    TCP [::1]:mysql (LISTEN)
    TCP 127.0.0.1:mysql (LISTEN)

But if I run my python script I only see the following, it doesn't say anything about mysql listening.

    TCP xx.xxx.17.87:62557->xx.x.xxx.133:ssh (ESTABLISHED)

Comment: honestly don't know why it wouldn't work at this point... if it were me, I would just wrap the ssh call to create the tunnel and the call to python in a bash script that calls both. i'll update the answer, this might help..

Comment: Your suggestion actually worked after I restarted my machine. Don't know why it didn't work earlier. Thanks a lot for your help. Here is the command I used.

ssh -NL 3306:remote.db.host:3306 username@hostname