# SSH Tunnel - ports issue?

Tags: linux, ssh, permissions, port

I'm having an issue with an SSH tunnel and I understand it may be a permissions issue with my local ports, most probably 127.0.0.1:3308.  However I've run my program as an administrator (`sudo python3 myprogram.py`) and I still have the same problem - but surely the administrator should have access to everything?  I've tried searching on here and Googling "permission on local ports" but I didn't find anything useful.

Context: I'm still trying to complete step 2 of [my original request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36833425/connection-to-remote-mysql-db-from-python-3-4).  I didn't get very far with my original question so [I asked again on Github](https://github.com/pahaz/sshtunnel/issues/58) which is where I got the feedback about the permissions issue.

I'm also not sure what tags to put on this question - feel free to improve them.  For me, this is Python 3 on a Raspberry Pi but if it's an issue with permissions then it's probably not specific to Python and it's likely to be Linux generally rather than Raspian specifically!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any feedback on why this was downvoted?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in this end, this wasn't an issue with permissions on ports (which is maybe why the question was downvoted) so I'm closing this question.  I'll put the solution on the original question.